# Как правильно удалить матрицу?

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор, деструктор

Как правильно удалить матрицу? У меня возникает такая ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <windows.h>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
class Graph {
private:
    bool** adjMatrix;
    bool** Pmatrix;
    int numVertices;
    int* p; // перестановка
public:
    Graph(int numVertices) {
        this->numVertices = numVertices;
        adjMatrix = new bool* [numVertices];
        Pmatrix = new bool* [numVertices];
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            adjMatrix[i] = new bool[numVertices];
            Pmatrix[i] = new bool[numVertices];
            for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++) {
                adjMatrix[i][j] = false;
                Pmatrix[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
        p = new int[numVertices];
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
            p[i] = i;
    }

    int getNumVertices() {
        return numVertices;
    }

    void addEdge(int i, int j) {
        adjMatrix[i][j] = true;
        adjMatrix[j][i] = true;
    }

    int* getP() {
        return p;
    }

    bool** getAdjMatrix() {
        return adjMatrix;
    }

    int* retPer() {
        next_permutation(p, p + numVertices);
        cout << "Перестановка" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
            cout << p[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
        return p;
    }

    bool** retPmatrix(int* p) {  
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                Pmatrix[i][j] = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
            Pmatrix[p[i]][i] = true;
        return Pmatrix;
    }

    bool** traspPmatrix(bool** Pmatrix) {
        bool** tPmatrix = new bool* [numVertices];
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            tPmatrix[i] = new bool[numVertices];
            for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                tPmatrix[i][j] = Pmatrix[j][i];
        }
        return tPmatrix;
    }

    bool** mulMatrix(bool** A, bool** B) {
        bool** C = new bool* [numVertices];
        int i, j, k;
        for (i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            C[i] = new bool[numVertices];
            for (j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                C[i][j] = false;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                for (k = 0; k < numVertices; k++)
                    C[i][j] = C[i][j] || (A[i][k] && B[k][j]);
        }
        return C;
    }

    void printMatrix(bool** Matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            cout << i << " : ";
            for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                cout << Matrix[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    Graph(const Graph &graph) : adjMatrix(graph.adjMatrix), Pmatrix(graph.Pmatrix),
        numVertices(graph.numVertices), p(graph.p) {}

    ~Graph() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i) {
            delete[] adjMatrix[i];
            delete[] Pmatrix[i];
        }
        delete[] adjMatrix;
        delete[] Pmatrix;
        delete p;
    }
};

bool isIsomorph(Graph g1, Graph g2) {
    int* Per = g1.getP();
    bool** Iso = g1.mulMatrix(g1.mulMatrix(g1.retPmatrix(Per), g1.getAdjMatrix()), g1.traspPmatrix(g1.retPmatrix(Per)));
    if (g2.getAdjMatrix() == Iso)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    double start_time, end_time;
    Graph g1(4), g2(4);
    //GRAPH1////////
    g1.addEdge(0, 1);
    g1.addEdge(0, 2);
    g1.addEdge(1, 2);
    g1.addEdge(2, 3);
    //GRAPH2/////////
    g2.addEdge(0, 1);
    g2.addEdge(0, 2);
    g2.addEdge(1, 2);
    g2.addEdge(2, 3);
    
    if (g1.getNumVertices() == g2.getNumVertices()) {
        if (g1.getAdjMatrix() != g2.getAdjMatrix()) {
            cout << "Матрица смежности графа А" << endl;
            g1.printMatrix(g1.getAdjMatrix());
            cout << "Матрица смежности графа B" << endl;
            g2.printMatrix(g2.getAdjMatrix());
            cout << "Первоначальная перестановка = [0, 1, 2, 3]" << endl; //ее не видно

            start_time = omp_get_wtime();
            if (isIsomorph(g1, g2))
                cout << "Графы изоморфны" << endl;
            else
                cout << "Графы НЕ изоморфны" << endl;
            end_time = omp_get_wtime();
            printf("Время на замер времени %lf\n", end_time - start_time);
        }
        else
            cout << "Вы ввели идентичные графы с одинаковыми матрицами смежностями, проверка на изоморфизм не требуется" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Error: Количество вершин не совпадает, проверка на изоморфизм отклоняется" << endl;
}
```

Comment: а конструктор копирования у Вас есть?

Comment: @KoVadim нет, а нужно?

Comment: конечно нужно. Как только где то попытаетесь передать по значению (а это рано или поздно произойдет), то все, у Вас будут висящие указатели. Правило трех/пяти никто не отменял.

Comment: Показывайте использование... Или копирование, или присваивание - вот и результат: двойное удаление.

Comment: @Harry добавил весь код, и конструктор копирования через списки инициализации, не знаю правильно или нет

Comment: ломает все isIsomorph. хотя можно по ссылке на константу передать, немного отстрочит падение

Comment: *"добавил весь код"* - не надо вываливать весь свой код, надо составлять [mcve]. Собственно при его наличии тривиальные проблемы стали бы очевидны и вопрос бы не понадобился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну и смотрите, что будет, если вы вдруг сделаете копию:

```
 Graph(const Graph &graph) : adjMatrix(graph.adjMatrix), Pmatrix(graph.Pmatrix),
    numVertices(graph.numVertices), p(graph.p) {}
```

Указатели обеих объектов будут указывать на одно и то же место в памяти. Это - так называемое мелкое (поверхностное) копирование.

При удалении

```
~Graph() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i) {
        delete[] adjMatrix[i];
        delete[] Pmatrix[i];
    }
    delete[] adjMatrix;
    delete[] Pmatrix;
    delete p;
}
```

одни и те же указатели в двух объектах приведут к повторному освобождению памяти по одному и тому же адресу...

Здесь нужно глубокое копирование - т.е. выделение новой памяти под матрицу того же размера и перекопирование всех элементов...

Comment: Почему при сравнении матриц смежности
 if (g1.getAdjMatrix() != g2.getAdjMatrix()) {какой-то код}
Программа считает что они неравны и начинает выполнять "какой-то код", хотя при инициализации вершин и ребер, а также при распечатке в консоли они равны?

Comment: Потому что вы сравниваете **не** матрицы, а указатели на них.